# Why often hyperlinks fail to redirect to new page in asp,net app

Tags: http-status-code-302, post-redirect-get

I have hosted asp.net app in godaddy. Whenever any hyperlink is clicked, requested page is not loaded but responded with 302 found error status code and automatically  user is logged out and redirected to login page. Please help me, If i have make any configuration changes.

I have used absolute as well as relative url, but no use.
I tried to use below controls but nothing resolved my problem.

<asp:linkbutton runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/home.aspx" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-block" style="text-align: center; color: white; background-color: darkgoldenrod" Text="home"></asp:linkbutton>

home

<a href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("home.aspx") %>"  class="btn btn-default btn-block" style="text-align: center; color: white; background-color: darkgoldenrod">home

Comment: As you haven't shared any code, it's close to impossible to provide help. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? A hyperlink itself usually does not "redirect", not can it "fail to redirect", that's some behaviour of the browser

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase,     I have used anchor tags for redirecting,   <a href="Home.aspx" class="col-lg-offset-11 col-md-offset-11 btn btn-default btn-info">Home</a> .  I used relative and absolute urls also, and changed to asp hyperlink and link buttons also. but still issue did not resolve. I cleared all the cookie and caches also. url is correctly pointing to the page. Issue is always it gives 302 found status code and redirects to login page. Please help me if I have to make any configuration changes in web.config.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. Where did you configure any redirect? A `<a>` tag itself does not trigger any redirect